# Windows Form DataGridView Population From Entity Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have a Windows Form project with a DataGridView. I populate the datagridview from an entity framework model. The model is created by adding object from Visual Studio.

How can i populate DataGridView directly from Model?

I have try this code and to find online solution but nothing work in my application:

```
using (SABIntegrationEntitiesBackOff info = new SABIntegrationEntitiesBackOff())
{
   var data = (from ordine in info.SpRicezioneSpedizioniLights select ordine).ToArray().Reverse();
   dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = data.ToList() };
}
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Do you get an error? Try `dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();`

Comment: I don't have error but the datagridView is empty

Answer (score 0):

That is all  whatis needed:

dataGridView1.DataSource =  data.ToList();

Comment: Empty null or does not contain elements?

Comment: Data has 70 rows...datagridview 0

Comment: `dataGridView1.Datasource = data.ToList(); dataGridView1.Bind();`

Comment: dataGriView don't have bind function in Windows Form Application